# Handling signals in client that reads continuously

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I've implemented a TCP/IP client in Qt that reads data constantly (when reading function returns, it calls itself again).

Now I need to handle a signal coming from another object, but the constant reading doesn't let the signal to be handled, unless I call     `QCoreApplication::processEvents();`.

Is there another solution for this matter? Is there a way to check if a certain signal is waiting in the queue and according to the results, handle it?

Comment: Aren't you using the Qt network classes and their signals to handle reading asynchronously?

Comment: It wasn't fit for my purposes, so no. Using basic c sockets (I know its not the best practice but it was what I needed)

Comment: Likely QSocketNotifier, which requires your network code to be async anyhow. Non-async network code is extremely bad practice.

Comment: Why weren't the Qt network classes fit for your purposes?

Comment: Thanks everyone for not addressing my question about signals, I managed to solve it.